# How can I have named entities in asciidoctor?

Tags: entity, doctype, asciidoctor

I'm using asciidoctor with the docbook backend for books. In the past I wrote DocBook, which allows me to declare named entities that I use throughout the book:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE book [
<!ENTITY class     "Galactic TOP SECRET">
<!ENTITY project   "World Domination">
<!ENTITY product   "Illuminati Mind Control Chemtrail Spray System CSS-2020">
]>
<book ...>
     ...
     What about our &class; &project;?
     Is our &product; working?
     ...
</book>
```

:-)
I haven't found a way to tell asciidoctor to insert the `DOCTYPE` declaration between the XML processing instruction and the `<book>` element. So I resorted to `--no-header-footer` and prepending the header and footer lines. Is there a better way to do this? Something like a named entity definition directive? An include mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use Docbook entity declarations? Asciidoctor has "attributes" that can serve the same purpose: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#attributes

For example, you can define an attribute within your document:

```
:class: Galactic TOP SECRET
```

Then later in your document, you can use the attribute:

```
"Billy, come up to the front and address the {class}." said the teacher.
```

When you transform your document to Docbook, you would see:

```xml
<simpara>"Billy, come up to the front and address the Galactic TOP SECRET."
said the teacher.</simpara>
```

If you do have to use Docbook entity declarations, you might use some XSL to transform the XML you get into the XML you want.

Comment: The "attribute" mechanism. Cool! One of the features other tools don't have.